# How to specify output filenames combined with command-line arguments in OMNET++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

In general, the OMNeT++ output filenames are `workloadType-#r.sca`, or `workloadType-#r.vec`. We want to run different simulations with different command-line arguments to find best our best simulation parameters. So, we want the output filenames to be more distinguishable with command-line arguments.

For example:
if I have `-arg1 8  -arg2 12`, we wish to have `workloadType-#r-8-12.sca`. So, we know which file is from which simulation. Of course, we can run each at a time to manually label them. But this is too much work. If we can specify output filenames in OMNeT++, we can automate the process and run many simulations at the same time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `output-scalar-file` and `output-vector-file` configuration options (either from the command line i.e. `--output-scalar-file` or from the INI file). By default its value is `${resultdir}/${configname}-${iterationvarsf}#${repetition}.sca` so normally if you have different iteration variable values, you would get different file names.

For details, see the manual: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-options:config-options

I'm not sure what is actually `arg1`, but my feeling is that you are doing something that should be done differently. A simulation result should depend **ONLY** from the configuration name and the iteration variable values (and the initial seed), and all of those variables are part of the filename already.

Or from a different angle: if your simulation results depends on command line parameters other than `-r` and `-c` then you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: My feeling is that you just have to properly configure `iteration variables` in your INI file and the rest would be handled properly by OMNeT++. If you just want to run a specific combination of variables, you can specify that using the -r (run filter) option.

Comment: There are a few cases when this approach might be legit, for example when the actual values of the iteration variables are coming from an external source and they are not known in advance.